# opencpu server user libaries not available

Tags: r, opencpu

i updated my opencpu infrastructure:

- opencpu 1.6
- RStudio Version 1.0.44
- R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)

in /rstudio i install some packages

```
.libPaths()

[1] "/home/<myUser>/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"              
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                    
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

But /ocpu/user/ has no library content -.-

any idea?

Best regards,
Arthur

Comment: solves my issue by add this evn: R_LIBS_USER=~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3

Answer (score 0):

solves my issue by add this evn: R_LIBS_USER=~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3